# How to fetch data from firebase database using different parameters?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to fetch data from firebase database using different parameters?. I am facing difficulty in fetching data from table with column1 or column2. But, unable to do so.

Comment: Hi Rupesh. Could you put in more details? Specially some code snippets that you have so far.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have tables so you won't be able to do that. Also, there are no columns so you can't do that either. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [Firebase Getting Started Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)